# bluetooth protocol stack implementation

Tags: bluetooth

I want to know how to implement bluetooth protocol stack. Any good links or references will be appreciated. How and from where should I start

Thanks.

Comment: ARM, Android or Windows CE, C or C++

Comment: I am also interested in x86, Linux, C or C++

Answer (score 6):

All the standards and specs are available from [www.bluetooth.org](http://www.bluetooth.org). From the Core Specification to all the BlueTooth Profiles currently available. It might only take you a decade or so to assimilate that lot  :)

If you want to play with a BlueTooth stack I would recommend a Linux platform with the [Bluez stack](http://www.bluez.org/). Plus you can check out the source for Bluez itself. There is a Bluez API in almost any programming language you could want.

For devices, aside from a PC dongle, or Bluetooth built in to a laptop, most mobile phones support an amazing number of bluetooth profiles, as do other mobile devices.

If you want to build your own thing, there is an [Arduino platform with a BlueTooth module from BlueGiga](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardBluetooth), pretty sure it only does RFCOMM and SPP though.

There are numerous books, from a programmers POV. I chewed through [Bluetooth Essentials for Programmers](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Bluetooth-Essentials-Programmers-Albert-Huang/dp/0521703751/ref=sr_1_8?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1246864892&sr=1-8) but found it pretty light-weight. Doesn't go much beyond making an RFCOMM link.

Good Luck!